# Drupal, create multiple CCK input form in a page

Tags: forms, drupal, input, cck

I have CCK Members (title, age, ...) and because of the huge number of members I have, it would be tiresome to update some of the fields (sample below is age-field) one-by-one.

I need a way to build something like picture below with Drupal 6/7. Is this possible using Views? if not, any suggestions?

Here's the link for my illustration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9SXM.png

thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to perform tasks on multiple nodes, users, etc at a time.  I don't think the form will look the same way, but it will allow you to more easily update CCK fields (along with *many* other helpful operations) at one time.

Comment: thanks, I found that VBO combined with editablefields module can achieve that. Thanks!